# Can I return the contents of an enum as a list using an extension method?

Tags: c#

I have the following Enum:

```
public enum QuestionType {
    Check = 1,
    CheckAndCode = 2,
    na = 99
};

public static class QuestionTypeExtension
{
    public static string D2(this QuestionType key)
    {
        return ((int) key).ToString("D2");
    }
}
```

I already created an extension method that formats the output but now I have another requirement. What I need to do is to create an extension method that will return the contents of the enum into a list of the following class:

```
public class Reference {
   public string PartitionKey { get; set; } // set to "00"
   public int RowKey { get; set; } // set to the integer value
   public string Value { get; set; } // set to the text of the Enum
}
```

Is it possible to do this in an extension method?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
public static List<Reference> GetReferencesForQuestionType()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(QuestionType))
        .Cast<QuestionType>()
        .Select(x => new Reference
                         {
                             PartitionKey = "00", 
                             RowKey = (int)x, 
                             Value = x.ToString()
                         })
        .ToList();
}
```

If you want to create an instance of the `Reference`-class for just one element in an extenstion method try this:

```
public static Reference ToReference(this QuestionType questionType)
{
    return new Reference
                     {
                         PartitionKey = "00", 
                         RowKey = (int)questionType, 
                         Value = questionType.ToString()
                     };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But can I do this as an extension method?

Comment: Sorry but maybe I am getting confused. I wanted to return a list of type Reference. However maybe I cannot do this with an extension method. Is that correct or can I do it ?

Comment: See my edited answer. If you want a list of references for all values of the `enum` use the first snippet, for just one value you can use the extension method defined in the second one.
Putting the first snippet into an extension method is not possible, because that would be kind of a static extension method.

Comment: You could however convert the method implemented in the first snippet to a generic method: `public List<Reference> GetReferences<T>() {...}`

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
public static class QuestionTypeExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<Reference> Reference()
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(QuestionType)).OfType<QuestionType>().
            Select(qt=>new Reference(){ PartitionKey = "00", RowKey = (int)qt, Value = qt.ToString()});
    }
}
```

Comment: That extension is unneccessary - because the method parameter `key` is never used.

Comment: Yes but as I was just thinking it made it clear and would be easier.

Comment: Good point, an extension really makes no sense here, see edits.

Comment: @JustinHarvey So now we have had the same idea ;)